# Как получить JS а не HTML запрос методом .load из .js.erb

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Ситуация такая: делаю сайт с обновлением фрагментов страницы через AJAX. Если у клиента не работает javascript, то должна загружаться страница с макетом (layout), если работает - загружаться фрагмент страницы в определённый DIV.

**content_body** -это div в макете. в него загружается контент **\views\abonent\find\index.js.erb**

\views\abonent\find\index.js.erb:

```
$('#content_body').html("<%= escape_javascript render ('index') %>");
```

\views\abonent\find\_index.html.haml:

```
%table.find_table
  %tr
    %td.form_find_td
      #form_find_index
        = render :partial => 'form_find_index'
    %td
      #abonent_details
```

\views\abonent\find\_form_find_index.html.haml:

```
%table.form_find_table
%tr
    %th
        Пошук по рахунку:
%tr
    %td
        = form_tag('/abonent/find_lic', method: 'post', remote:true, :class=>'form_find_lic') do |f|
            = text_field_tag 'find[lic]', (@service ? @service.abcount.to_s : ''), maxlength: 12, size: 14,
            class:'form_find_lic_textfield',title:'Значення особового рахунку'
            = submit_tag 'пошук', :class=>'submit_button',
            title:'Введіть значення особового рахунку в поле зліва.'
```

\views\abonent\find\lic.js.erb:

```
$('#abonent_details').load("<%= abonent_path(@apartment.id) %>");
```

Получается: в форме **\views\abonent\find_form_find_index.html.haml** нажимаю кнопку поиска, происходит выполнение JSкода из **\views\abonent\find\lic.js.erb**. Дальше к серверу приходит запрос **Processing by Abonent::DetailsController#index as HTML**.
Хотелось бы получать запрос **Processing by ... as JS** чтобы в контроллере
**\controllers\abonent\details_controller.rb**:

```
class Abonent::DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @apartment = Apartment.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if !@apartment
        flash.alert = "Не найдена квартира."
        redirect_to :controller => 'abonent/find'
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js {
            render :layout => false
        }
    end
  end
end
```

можно было отрендерить фрагмент без макета в случае JS-запроса а в случае HTML-запроса отрендерить вместе с макетом.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  controller :start do
    #get 'start/index'
    get  '/accessdenied' => :accessdenied
  end
  namespace :abonent do
    controller :find do
        get  '/find'       => :index
        post '/find_lic'   => :lic
        post '/find_addr'  => :addr
    end
    controller :details do
        get  '/:id'        => :index
    end
  end
  root to: 'start#index', as: 'start'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение вопроса нашёл сам.
В контроллере **\controllers\abonent\details_controller.rb** нужно проверять **request.xhr?**

```
class Abonent::DetailsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @apartment = Apartment.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if !@apartment
        flash.alert = "Не найдена квартира."
        redirect_to :controller => 'abonent/find'
    end
    render :layout => false if request.xhr?
  end
end
```

Запрос из браузера от скрипта `$('#abonent_details').load("<%= abonent_path(@apartment.id) %>");` в любом случае приходит как HTML т.к. возвращается отрендеренный кусок HTML-текста.
Но в запросе через JS будет содержаться `request.xhr?`